# Encourage companies to promote their diversity policy and reduce terms that imply discrimination

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

Can SE Careers provide features to help employers attract from the widest pool possible and do more to prevent inadvertent discrimination?

1. Highlight to advertisers that they are using implied terms that could put off a subset of potential candidates (maybe you already do?).
2. Pass ads through a [gender decoder](http://gender-decoder.katmatfield.com/) to help people write ads that don't discourage people from applying because of their gender.
3. Encourage companies to include a link to their diversity/equality policy on ads. (Like they do to encourage companies to highlight their adherence to the Joel Test)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creating ways to encourage companies to promote their diversity and inclusion efforts is a great idea. We have several customers who have expressed they would like to highlight their efforts in this area more openly and we've heard from job seekers that this sort of company information is helpful when considering new opportunities. As for job listings, our customer support team does play a role in coaching customers to craft clear and inclusive job listings where possible but we certainly don't review every listing and rely heavily on the community to flag anything inappropriate or offensive.

We appreciate your feedback and ideas here and more are welcome. We don't have any specific solutions yet but our product team is thinking about this topic and hope to prioritize some of this work in the coming months so this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this @Des. #1 & #2 on my post were just (controversial!) suggestions for highlighting potential areas for improvement to companies writing job posts, not to do with offensive or inappropriate ads. As you say, I think item 3 on my list (or something similar) would provide the most value to companies and job seekers.

Answer (score 27):

For the reasons discussed in the comments, an automated approach that scans employers' listings for certain words is not a good idea.

For one, it wouldn't work very well. The "gender decoder" you link to is a very primitive word checker - with the typical [downsides of a very primitive word checker.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem) While it's clear what the authors of that tool are trying to convey, the [word list they use](https://github.com/lovedaybrooke/gender-decoder/blob/master/app/wordlists.py) seems patently absurd, laughable if not pretty offensive.

For another, [people don't like having their language policed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/why-cant-we-use-the-word-problem-in-titles). Probably even more so when they're paying a lot of money for the privilege.

However, Stack Overflow jobs has a [blog.](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/blog) Advice on how to optimize the wording of  developer job listings is the thing they talk about most there. A feature request for a blog post on the topic might make a more productive approach.

Comment: Yes, the decoder suggestion has been controversial. It's supposed to be a suggestion tool on the input side to help an employer craft an universally appealing ad. It would not prevent them from using the phrase "competitive salary" or do anything that could be "game-able". Btw, for all I know SO is already doing something like this on the employer side. I apologise if I didn't make this clear enough in my question.

Comment: @conradj I'm just a mod and not staff - but I believe you can't even post a job ad now without talking to a member of the sales team so I'd like to think at that point some advice is given on how to get best results - don't know though.

Comment: [Textio](https://textio.com/), a Seattle based startup, provides this very functionality and it is proving popular with employers. I think providing this kind of feature could be great, but you don't want to force people to use it.